# VBA - Copy and paste the data from the 4th column

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use my other similar VBA code but I don't think I understand what I'm trying to replace for the range. In this code, I am trying to copy the data in the Repeating Items sheet in the fourth column with the cell value of 12, then paste it to the last worksheet.

```
' Repeating items worksheet
    Worksheets("Repeating Items").Select

    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

    b = Worksheets("Repeating Items").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Filters the data where column 2 equals to 12 to x. ** this is where the error starts
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(b, 4)).Autofilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="12", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    ' Selects only the filtered cells and copy
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(b, 4)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
```

Comment: What is the problem / what line throws an error / what is the error message?

Comment: AutoFilter method of range class failed

Comment: Just filter the first row. `Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter), you can just apply the filter to the first row much how you would manually do in excel and it will automatically filter your range. You don't need to quote your number filter FYI (unless the column is *Text*).

Also, no need to `Select` anything here. It is just a middle man operator that only slows your code down. Instead, explicitly define your objects (sheets and ranges) and skip right to the action statements *(copy/paste)*.

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Repeating Items")
Dim ls As Worksheet: Set ls = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=12

ws.Range("A2:D" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ls.Range("A" & ls.Range("A" & ls.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. It still shows the same error that autofilter method of range class failed at ws.Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=12